# Soldering a Reed switch upside down into a slot

Tags: soldering, ipc

I would like to solder Coto reed switch CT10-2540-G1 upside down into a slot. It would recede into the slot until the tips of the lead touched the pads.

[image]

[image]

Is there an IPC standard regarding the minimum pad coverage that would be required?
I kept 0.3mm distance from the slot edge to the pad. I would like to make this smaller but my DRC flags anything less than 0.635mm and am hesitant to bring it any closer.

Comment: This could work, but consider a drop of mild adhesive in the cut-out for support; the solder bond will likely be weaker.

Comment: Careful about using adhesive *on the brittle glass enclosure* -- it depends on flexible leads to avoid cracking due to thermal cycling.